# Vpython 6 - installation on Ubuntu 14.06 from source code

Tags: python

I have a Ubuntu 14.06 and I would like install a VPython 6 (http://vpython.org/contents/download_linux.html). I followed the instuctions and the used the script file available on `github.com/katanachan/installer/blob/master/VisualPythonInstaller.sh`.
However, I got the error message:

```
wxPython-src-2.9.5.0.patch
./VisualPythonInstaller.sh: 95: cd: can't cd to vpython-wx-src.6.11/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 51, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Sorry.. you need to install wxPython (at least 2.9.x) to build this version of vpython")
```

The purpose of my message is to find out if any user have successfully done the installationof Vpython 6.

Thank you on advance.

Comment: Did you install `wxPython`?

Comment: Dear George, I could not to do the installation of wxPython. There is no wxPython-3.0 on Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Try this `pip install -U --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix ` found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029760/wxpython-in-python-3-4-1)